# Displaying images in gsp(grails)

Tags: grails, frameworks

I am very new to grails.I am doing one sample project for image uploading and displaying.Right now my project uploads the images and stores into the images directory.Now i want to display all the images stored in the "image" directory.
I dont know how to write the gsp code for display all images.

For displaying the images I wrote the following code in list.gsp page.

My gsp code is:

```
<g:each in="${imageList}" var="image">
<img src="${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: '1.jpg')}" alt="Grails"/>
</g:each>
```

imageList has filenames of images in the image directory.

In the second line i want put filename instead of  "1.jpg".

Can any one tell me how to display the images.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your imageList has list of image objects try the following

**${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: image.filename)}.**

If your imageList like this['1.jpg','2.jpg','3.jpg'] try the following

```
**${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: image)}**
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what's in your imageList, you can do a :

```
<g:each in="${imageList}" var="image">
<img src="${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: image.filename)}" alt="Grails"/>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your `imageList` is something like `['1.jpg', '2.jpg', ...]`, your `createLinkTo` should just look like:

```
${createLinkTo(dir: 'images', file: image)}
```

Since you've already defined the iterator variable as 'image'. If that doesn't work, it might help to clarify what's in the contents of your `imageList` collection.